Mojo how to vectorize and parallelize function
I am trying to speed up the following function in Mojo:
    for i in range(ni):
        for j in range(nj):
            for k in range(nk):
                E[i,j] += A[i,k] * B[k,j]                

    for i in range(nj):
        for j in range(nl):
            for k in range(nm):
                F[i,j] += C[i,k] * D[k,j]

    for i in range(ni):
        for j in range(nl):
            for k in range(nj):
                G[i,j] += E[i,k] * F[k,j]

I am considering how to change it so to use the vectorize() and parallelize()
functionts available. I am following this similar example they have in their docs here:https://docs.modular.com/mojo/notebooks/Matmul#vectorizing-the-inner-most-loop
My attempt at this was the following for the first dot product:
alias nelts = simdwidthof[DType.float32]() * 2

fn kernel_3mm_vector(A:Matrix, B:Matrix, C:Matrix, D:Matrix, E:Matrix, F:Matrix, G:Matrix) :
    @parameter
    fn calc(i: Int):
        for i in range(ni):
            @parameter
            fn vector1[nelts: Int](j: Int):
                for k in range(nk):
                    E.store(i, j, E.load[nelts](i, j) + A[i,k] * B.load[nelts](k, j))
            vectorize[vector1, nelts, size = nj]()
    parallelize[calc](ni, ni)

But somehow the function is slower now than before. Any insights on how to correctly implement those functions?
